# SQLite ERROR no such column Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a problem, i am trying to do a validation between a username to that username email by compairing the rowid in python and SQLite, here is the code:

```
username = self.txtUsername.GetValue()
email =  self.txtEmail.GetValue()
UsernameE  = self.conn.execute("SELECT rowid,* FROM tblPlayers WHERE p_Username="
  + username)
EmailU = self.conn.execute("SELECT rowid,* FROM tblPlayers WHERE p_Email=" + email)
```

The error is:

```
> UsernameE  = self.conn.execute("SELECT rowid,* FROM tblPlayers WHERE p_Username="
      + username)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: "what i inserted in the username"
```

Comment: Use indentation rather than backticks for blocks of code. I'd change it but it's too small an edit to be allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL is malformed, because you don't close the quote after the username value. But you shouldn't be doing it that way anyway: you should be using a parameter:

```
self.conn.execute("SELECT rowid,* FROM tblPlayers WHERE p_Username=? ", (username,))
```

Also note that execute doesn't return the value: you need to fetch it, eg with `fetchone()`.

Comment: it worked but the value of username and email is similar to 0x0316... how do i convert it to the actual string behind this value? tried using fetchone() and fetchall() but i get that sqlite.connection has no attribute for this

Comment: You need to get a cursor (`cur = self.conn.cursor()`) and call both execute and fetchone on that, rather than directly on the connection object.

Comment: tried but the return value of each variable is None

Answer (score 0):

Try adding quotes to username:

```
UsernameE  = self.conn.execute("SELECT rowid,* FROM tblPlayers WHERE p_Username = '" + username + "'")
```